# How to setup a report database which real-time replicate production database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We need to seperate report from production database because it slows the server, but real-time data is important, can't accept daily replicate production database.

Do you have suggestions for this kind of scenario? Thanks.

We are using Sql Server 2005.

Comment: How time-sensitive does it need to be? Is the acceptable difference measured in hours, minutes, or seconds?

Comment: @JustinStolle half an hour delay can be accepted

Comment: Why does the server slow? Hardware, Locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Log shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189572%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) or [transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to the reporting server are possible solutions. Alternatively, you could build a lightweight ETL process to move the data. That might work well if you're only interested in a well-defined subset of the complete database (although replication could do that too); Google "real time data warehousing" for some ideas.